# jdbcDigestAuthentication only works when providing the hash

Tags: java, digest-authentication, jdbcrealm

I started a project setting up basic authentication. I now want to switch to Digest Authentication. The problem is that the authentication is validated only if I provide the hash of the actual password, and not the actual password.

I did the following to switch from BASIC to DIGEST:

1. changed in my web.xml the auth-method to DIGEST
2. changed the JAAS context of my JDBC Realm to "jdbcDigestRealm"
3. in my db, I used to have "password" as a password, I changed in to the result of MD5(webuser:postgres:webuser) (where webuser is the login, webuser is the password, and postgres is the realm), in other words I set the password in my table to c3c2681ed07a5a2a5cb772061a8385e8.

The problem I have is that the login popup is displayed by the browser when I try to access the resource, but using "webuser" as the password doesn't work. However, using "c3c2681ed07a5a2a5cb772061a8385e8" as the password works. It looks like I'm still in BASIC authentication mode.

Any clue ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DIGEST auth-method is same as HTTP Digest Authentication. It just encrypts the communication between the browser and the server. The server still has the password in plain text.

From http://java.boot.by/wcd-guide/ch05s03.html:

> The difference between basic and digest authentication is that on the
>   network connection between the browser and the server, the password is
>   encrypted, even on a non-SSL connection. In the server, the password
>   can be stored in clear text or encrypted text, which is true for all
>   login methods and is independent of the choice that the application
>   deployer makes.

You should set the `digest-algorithm` property of your `JDBC Realm` to `MD5`. After that the JDBC Realm will hash the password.

Comment: Ok ! To me the password was stored ciphered in the database ... Having it in plaintext is such a poor design to me. I guess I'l have to customize this ! Thanks for pointing out this detail : Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you may need to change the digest algorithm in the realm view from glassfish console to MD5. Default value from GlassFish 3.0.* is still MD5, but from GlassFish 3.1.* has changed to SHA-256. This could be solution.

Adem

Comment: Tried this but always needed to store the password in plaintext in the database. This is expected behaviour, see accepted answer below ! Thanks for your help anyway Adem.